# What can cause an Arduino to "disconnect" from Windows?

Tags: hardware

I bought a DFrobot Beetle and it worked fine for probably an hour, then it just stopped working with Windows.

When I connect it to the computer I hear the "connect" sound, then within 5-7 seconds I hear the disconnect sound again.

I didn't do anything special with it. I connected a RDM6300 rfid reader and used an example code from a library.
I think the last thing I did was to change a string output message in the console.

From then on it just disconnects.
I tried to email DFrobot but didn't get a reply.

What could have caused this?
What can I do to make it work again?
The reset pin didn't work.
There is not enough time to replace the code on the board before it disconnects.

Comment: What's the USB chip? is it CH340 or CP2102? if it's CH340 try installing the windows driver for it. [Link](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all).

Comment: I don't know. How can I see that? On the chip it says "MEGA32U4"  \n "-MJ" \n "1812E PH" \n "1812E81"

Comment: Can you please post a link to the actual product?

Comment: This is the place I bought it from https://www.tme.eu/en/details/df-dfr0282/programmable-controllers/dfrobot/dfr0282/ . DFrobot product page https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Beetle_SKU_DFR0282

Comment: Seems it don't a have USB chip on it but read the Introduction section. [Link](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1075.html). Did you select Arduino Leonardo in Arduino IDE before programing it? Also read [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299712/how-is-the-atmega32u4-chip-recognized-via-usb). and the AtMega32u4 [Driver](https://learn.adafruit.com/atmega32u4-breakout/download).

Comment: Yes I had Leonard selected, and it worked fine for an hour with probably 10 different codes. I will try the driver, but not today. Going to bed soon. Thanks!

Comment: do a double reset and the upload some working sketch. the USB is handled by the sketch